# ring.middleware and compojure: params with keywords

Tags: clojure, compojure, ring

In my web handler, I have the following defined:

```
(:require ... 

[ring.middleware.cookies :refer [wrap-cookies]]
            [ring.middleware.multipart-params :refer [wrap-multipart-params]]
            [ring.middleware.params :refer [wrap-params]]
            [ring.middleware.keyword-params :refer [wrap-keyword-params]]
            [ring.middleware.content-type :refer [wrap-content-type]]
            [ring.middleware.format-response :refer [wrap-restful-response]
...)

(def app
  (-> (routes home/my-routes)
      (wrap-cookies)
      (wrap-params)
      (wrap-multipart-params)
      (wrap-keyword-params))))
```

Everything works.  Testing with curl using a URL that looks like "../test?foo=123" gives me a params map that looks like {:foo 123}.  However, what appears as a keyword is actually a string: (keyword? :foo) returns false.

I've tried rearranging the handlers and removing them one at a time, but to no avail.  Is there something about compojure that is converting the keywords back into strings?  Thanks

Comment: Did you mean: `(keyword? ":foo")`?

Comment: No:  I did this:  (println "is keyword " (keyword? (key (first params))))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`wrap-keyword-params` middleware should be run after `wrap-params` and `wrap-multipart-params`, so your app should look like:

```
(def app
  (-> (routes home/my-routes)
      (wrap-keyword-params)
      (wrap-cookies)
      (wrap-params)
      (wrap-multipart-params))))
```

Comment: To avoid similar problems in the future, you might consider using https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring-defaults