# How to get the client IP address in ring-clojure?

Tags: clojure, ring

When a visitor submit a form, I'd like to assoc to inputs his IP adress.

```
(POST "/form" {params :params} (assoc params :ip-address the-ip)
```

How to do this?

Thought of doing this:

```
(POST "/form" {params    :params
               client-ip :remote-addr} 
      (->> params keywordize-keys (merge {:ip-address client-ip}) str))
```

But this returns  `{... :ip-address "0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1"}`

Comment: well this is `localhost` in ipv6. where does your request originate from?

Comment: @cfrick localhost. Yeah. I couldn't test this in prod so wasn't sure about `:remote-addr` form your answer, I suppose this is right.

Comment: BTW just found out I don't need to use a keywordize-keys fn. Just need `wrap-keyword-params` . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26151801/ring-middleware-and-compojure-params-with-keywords

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From Arthur Ulfeldt's comment to Bill's answer, I guess we could write this:

```
(defn get-client-ip [req]
  (if-let [ips (get-in req [:headers "x-forwarded-for"])]
    (-> ips (clojure.string/split #",") first)
    (:remote-addr req)))
```

Comment: // , Will this return an IPv6 address, though?

Comment: @NathanBasanese If I get your question correctly, my answer would be I didn't test form an IPV6 source. I do not know if it will return such a string correctly..

Answer (score 6):

Getting `:remote-addr` from the request object is typically the correct way to go unless you're sitting behind a load balancer. In that case your load balance may add a header e.g. `x-forwarded-for` to the request. Which would make something like this appropriate.

```
(or (get-in request [:headers "x-forwarded-for"]) (:remote-addr request))
```

Comment: This will fail for clients that are themselves behind a proxy, because the x-forwarded-for will be a comma separated list of IPs like "2.2.2.2,5.5.5.5" with the actual address you want as everything *before* the first `,` and keep in mind they can be IPv6 addresses as well even if your service is on IPv4

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can get this information from the ring request object. Have a look at the ring.middleware.dump (handle-dump) package. If you set that up and a simple route to use it, you will get a nice web page showing all the available values provided in a ring request object. Pretty sure this includes the client IP address. As this information is obtained from the http headers, it will likely be more reliable than manually putting it into your request parameters - putting it into your request parameters either using a form or json could mean it is easier to forge. Besides, if it is already readily available as part of the request object, means one less ting you need to do.